# Multiple words in function type declaration confuses me

Tags: haskell

I understand haskell's function type declaration like,

```
length :: String -> Int
prefix :: Int -> String -> String
```

But sometimes, the types on the right side are not simple types like `String`, `Integer` but it contains multiple literal words, and the words that look like custom defined etc.

For example, these types defined on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253315/simple-debugging-in-haskell),

```
withLocation :: Q Exp -> Q Exp
```

What does Q, Exp mean?

```
formatLoc :: Loc -> String
```

What does Loc mean? Is it part of haskell library?

Comment: You're asking three questions in a single post. Limit posts to a single question.

Comment: The answer to most of your question is: you have something called [kinds  in Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) - it's one step above types - so your `String` here has kind `*` and your `Q` has kind `* ->  *` meaning: you have to give `Q` a type (something of kind `*`) and it will result in something of kind `*` (another type) - this is why you have to put both there - it's almost the same as with functions / partial application, ...

Comment: for the other: there are a couple of types named `Loc` that [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Loc) will find - if you look at the question it will be the one in [Language.Haskell.TH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Loc) I think - how to get emacs to work here is quite another question that depends on your emacs installation and your environment there ... this might be a lot of pain (and I usually don't care - use Hadock instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types `Q`, `Exp` and `Loc` are types from the Template Haskell module imported at the beginning of the source file.

`Q` is a parameterized type, just like, say, `Maybe` or `IO` from the prelude, which is here applied to `Exp`.

> How to do `goto defintion` from emacs editor?

This can be achieved using [Scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion#experimental-features), but that won't help you for this use case as it does not allow you to jump into external libraries (which may not be available in source form anyway).