# How does GHC implement unsafePerformIO?

Tags: linux, haskell, ghc

Starting from `unsafePerformIO` and ending at either the RTS, libc, or an OS API, how does GHC implement IO?

---

I'm trying to get a sense of how IO works in Haskell when the standard prelude isn't available (e.g. if we were implementing the standard prelude ourselves for whatever reason).

I was originally expecting to find wrapped calls to C functions in GHC's Haskell code, but that's not the case. `unsafePerformIO` is built on top of `runRW#` which is where heavy magic begins and we start crashing into functions and types that aren't implemented in Haskell and are instead built into the compiler. `runRW#` appears to be able to run an IO action on the state of the real world (i.e. a `State# RealWorld`).

Trying to go from the other direction, I haven't found a foothold in the RTS. It doesn't appear to contain the calls I would expect to functions like `fread()` and `fwrite()` or `read()` and `write()`.

Where do I continue following the IO implementation from here? What is the basic roadmap from here onwards?

Comment: At runtime the representation of `IO X` and `X` are identical. unsafePerformIO is just the identity.

Comment: @user2407038 IO actions also produce side-effects.

Comment: @Praxeolitic What you said is in fact not evidence that user2407038 is wrong. (Nevertheless, they are wrong: `IO X` has the same representation as a function that returns an `X` and some other data in an unboxed tuple.)

Comment: @user2407038 That's not true at all.  The runtime represenation of `IO X` is a function.  Try running `(unsafeCoerce (putStrLn "Hello World!") :: () -> ()) ()` in ghci. It will crash, but it will produce output.

Comment: Just for reference: `newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))`. Nether `State#` nor `RealWorld` actually exist at runtime. `State# s` simply represents a state token: it gets threaded around like in a normal state monad to sequence actions: `(IO f) >>= g = IO $ \s -> case f s of (# s', x #) -> unIO (g x) s'` vs `(State f) >>= g = State $ \s -> case f s of (s', x) -> runState (g x) s'`, but it goes \*poof\* sometime during compilation. If you take out the tokens in `IO a`, it's runtime representation looks a bit like `() -> a`, but this'll be an impure function.

Comment: This is explained here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Evaluation_order_and_state_tokens  Read about state tokens and IO model in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can recall, a value of type `IO x` is really a function from `RealWorld#` to a [strict] tuple of `RealWorld#` and `x`. In other words, a simple state monad.

You won't find `read()` etc in the RTS itself; I believe the usual Prelude interface calls them via FFI. That is, the code to do it is in the `base` package, not in the RTS itself. (The RTS *does*, however, house its own thread-scheduler, which presumably calls `pthread` or whatever. And also the garbage collector and memory manager, which probably call `mmap`.)

At least, I *believe* that's how it works, as best as I can remember. Needless to say, this is all *highly* specific to GHC's particular implementation, rather than part of any official Haskell language specification.